# Android subscription/purchase is not found in code despite being defined in Google Play Console

Tags: android, kotlin, android-inapp-purchase, revenuecat

I am trying to add a subscription to my app. I have created a subscription called "pro_subscription" in the Google Play Console and made sure it's enabled. I then created a new Alpha build and released it to myself, with an account I have configured for testing.

We added `com.android.vending.BILLING` to the permissions and already had the internet permission.

No matter what we've tried, when we try to fetch the subscription in order to purchase it, no results are found.

We have tried to fetch using Android APIs directly, in which `mutableList?.isEmpty()` is `true`:

```
fun querySkuDetails() {
    val purchasesUpdatedListener =
        PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
            // To be implemented in a later section.
        }

    var billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity as MainActivity)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
                skuList.add("subscription")
                skuList.add("pro_subscription")
                val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), SkuDetailsResponseListener() { billingResult: BillingResult, mutableList: MutableList<SkuDetails>? ->
                    if (mutableList?.isEmpty()!!) {
                        Log.d("OFFERS: ", "mutableList is empty")
                        return@SkuDetailsResponseListener
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    })
```

And we also tried using the third-party revenuecat by configuring an offering and then fetching it, in which `offerings.all.isEmpty()` is `true`:

```
Purchases.sharedInstance.getOfferingsWith(
    onError = { error ->
        /* Optional error handling */
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    },
    onSuccess = { offerings ->
        if (offerings.current == null) {
            Log.d("OFFERS: ", "offerings.current is null")
        }
        if (offerings.all.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("OFFERS: ", "offerings.all.size is 0")
        }
        // Display current offering with offerings.current
        Purchases.sharedInstance.purchasePackageWith(
            activity as MainActivity,
            offerings.current?.getPackage("pro")!!,
            onError = { error, userCancelled -> /* No purchase */
                if (userCancelled) {
                    val requestCancelledToast = Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        R.string.purchase_request_cancelled_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                    requestCancelledToast.show()
                } else {
                    throw IllegalArgumentException()
                }
            },
            onSuccess = { product, purchaserInfo ->
                if (purchaserInfo.entitlements["pro"]?.isActive == true) {
                    // Unlock that great "pro" content
                    try {
                        val adView =
                            container!!.findViewById<AdView>(R.id.adView)
                        (adView.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(
                            adView
                        )
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        val errorRemoveToast = Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            R.string.error_remove_ad,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        )
                        errorRemoveToast.show()
                    }
                }
            })
    })
```

In both cases, no error is printed, caught, or otherwise identified.

Anyone know why we are not able to fetch the purchases based on the above steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add Library of billing on the app's gradle?

It is;

```
dependencies {
    val billing_version = "4.0.0"

    implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version")
}
```